# List all primary and secondary Indexes in Amazon DynamoDB for a Table using BOTO-Python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I have a table in Amazon DynamoDB. I dont have the schema of the table. So i used 'DescribeTable()' function. It lists me the key schema as

```
u'KeySchema': 
 {u'RangeKeyElement': 
     {u'AttributeName': u'PUT_TIMESTAMP', 
      u'AttributeType': u'S'}, 
  u'HashKeyElement': 
     {u'AttributeName': u'DATASET_ID', 
      u'AttributeType': u'S'}
 }
```

Is there anyway i can get the list of secondary indexes related to the table, or check if secondary indexes are present in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the `boto.dynamodb` module or `boto.dynamodb2`?  If you are using boto.dynamodb2 it should return all local and global secondary indexes in a call to `describe_table()`.  The `boto.dynamodb` module is based on an older version of the service API prior to the secondary index features.

Comment: I am using boto.dynamodb. I know in dynamodb2 it's possible, but is there anyway in boto.dynamodb to do the same?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not.  The ``boto.dynamodb`` module uses the ``2011-12-05`` version of the DynamoDB API  and that API does not support additional indexes.